# configuring a Windows Server 2012 VM using IIS to call Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm setting up an ASP.NET MVC5 application on a Windows Server 2012 VM running .Net 4.5 and IIS8.  I've always leverages Azure for App and DB services (thank you Azure for your seamless 10 min server setup and publishing solution!) however I need to host this app using this alternative method.  The VM is not an Azure VM.   I've managed to configure the VM and publish the application (10 hrs of head banging experience... ) however when the application attempts to make a call to the Azure Db during the form registration process I receive a time out error; "The wait operation timed out".

My question is;    I can access the application via the ip address from my local machine, I think port 80 is open by default.  Do I need to specifically target this port in the applications web.config file for I/O calls?

Comment: Is your VM behind a firewall?

Comment: When you say your Non-Azure VM is connecting to your Azure DB, is it SQL database on Azure (PaaS) or a database running on an Azure VM?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect a non-Azure Virtual machine which is behind a firewall to the resources in Azure, you will have to create a virtual network with either site to site or point to site VPN enabled. Please check this link which explains how to do it. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal/

Comment: Thanks Gandhali.  I'll post back if this is successful.